# How do I decrease shared memory usage?

Tags: 16.04, memory-usage

I am suffering from frequent lock-ups of my desktop system (see [Memory full, mostly taken by "shared", GUI unresponsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980372/)).

Example output of `free -m`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15943        2583        3176        9063       10183        3574
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Why are > 9 GB taken by shared? How do I force this to be less?

Comment: Increase the swappines!

Comment: swappiness won't help if `Swap: 0 0 0`.  It appears he has no swap set up.

Comment: @DavidO why does one setup Ubuntu xenial without swap, OP did you remove your swap or never created one?

Comment: @George you will have to ask the OP why he did that and how. I just made the observation that it appears he has no swap.

Comment: @DavidO I agree with you on that just wondering why one who has no experience with Ubuntu will do such a thing rather than follow the standard setup process!

Comment: I have delibrately disabled swap. My question is not about swap though but about the huge amount of memory reserved as shared memory.

Comment: This looks interesting though: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762717/high-shmem-memory-usage?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that would have been my next suggestion @fuenfundachtzig: Check df -h and see how much is being consumed by each of the tmpfs entries.  On my system with 32GB RAM I have mapped `/tmp` to tmpfs also, so in theory I could fill my RAM and dive into swap if some process decided to spin out of control writing tempfiles.  But in practice that's pretty unlikely, and even if it did happen, I wouldn't much appreciate 32G of temp files ending up on a physical drive either, so memory+swap for /tmp is a reasonable arrangement for me (and performant).

Answer (score 0):

I know it won't help but for anyone who needs to fix this
You should probably do it through bios
Imp There should some part of ram given to igpu
Go to bios
Select uma buffer size and select the lowest size possible
If you have option don't turn it completely off
I would prefer 1 gb if you have 16gb and 512 MB if you have 8gb
You can increase these as per your needs :)